# I can't link my JQuery file to my HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to link my JQuery file to my HTML file no matter what I try. The JQuery code itself works when I put it in a script section on the HTML page but doesn't work from the file.

Heres the head for my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Index page-->

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- CSS file link -->
    <link href="login-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- JQuery link -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and the bottom of the body:

```
    <!-- Bootstrap jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the JQuery code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(window).on('load', function () {
      alert("For this prototype please use admin as username and password as password");
 });

</script>
```

Comment: `.js` files must have JavaScript code, not HTML tags.

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools console?

Comment: Why are you importing jQuery *twice* (once at the top and again at the end)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have called jquery cdn at two place, remove it from head.
2. and just add your Jquery.js file below the Jquery cdn at bottom of your page, and see the magic.
3. and no need to call Jquery cdn in your JS file, remove it from there too

Comment: You are a life saver thank you. I'm still a newbie at all this.

Comment: Your welcome, If this answer helped you, don't forget to mark it right answer, and I will be happy to help you more if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

above is not best practice to include jquery. Better use `defer` instead as follow:

```
<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>
```